# Javascript date parse error

Tags: javascript, datetime

I'm trying to convert string into epoch time in milliseconds using specs found on:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

For some reason the following snippet of codes returns March 13 instead of Feb 24, 2014.

**Snippet 1:**

```
alert(Date(Date.parse("2014-02-24T09:49:22.000-0800")));
```

**Output:** Thu Mar 13 2014 21:51:41 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)

**Snippet 2:**

```
alert(Date(Date.parse("2014-02-24")));
```

**Output:** Thu Mar 13 2014 21:51:41 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)

Is this some sort of timezone issue or what is the mistake that i have done ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `new`

```
alert(new Date(Date.parse("2014-02-24")))
```

Comment: Wow, it was that simple? Thanks. If I was only doing the Date.parse should I put new in front of it as well?

Comment: No.  Date.parse is correct.  Any [constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) should use `new`.

Comment: Actually, you can simplify it down to `console.log(new Date("2014-02-24T09:49:22.000-0800"))`.  `new Date` can also parse for itself.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
function parseDate(input) {
  var parts = input.split('-');
  return new Date(parts[0], parts[1]-1, parts[2]); // Note: months are 0-based
}
```

**or**

```
console.log(new Date(Date.parse("2014-02-08T00:00:00Z")).toString());
```